# Resize an imported bitmap image in photoshop through dialog box

Tags: adobe, photoshop

So I just moved from Adobe Fireworks to Photoshop.  I imported an image (bitmap) in photoshop and wanted to resize it, not through the handles, but by giving exact dimensions. Unlike fireworks where it gives editable dimensions and you can manipulate them in real time, I don't find any such options here. In fact, the properties dialog box is empty! doesn't show anything at all.

Can someone please guide me how to resize images in photoshop, by giving dimensions?

thx.

Answer (score 0):

You could do two things:

1. Go to `Image > Image Size` or press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> in `Windows` or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> in `MacOS`.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in `Windows` or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in `MacOS` and next go to the `W` and `H` fields in the above options and insert the exact values with the `px` text at the end for exact sizing. (This method only resizes the `layer`, not the entire image)

Comment: Hi elchininet, thanks, here's the issue...
So when I do it with CTRL+T, in the properties pane, it shows width and height in percentage, even though I had set them in pixels previously.

When I select the image and press Alt+Ctrl+I, I get the dialog box that has the image of the full canvas, and not the bitmap I selected.  

What i'm probably looking for, is a dialog box like in Fireworks, where I can probably go to a properties pane, and add width and height in pixels.  Can I do that some how?

Comment: `Photoshop` does not have the same `Fireworks`'s property panel. Like I said, if you hit **CTRL + T** and next write the values with the "px" text at the end (delete the value with percents). With this method you could resize the image by an exact number of pixels (you could use cm, mm, etc too) and `Photoshop` will remembers the measure type that you are selected. If you press the icon between `W` and `H` you can maintain the image aspect ratio.